# Unity 3D CS0246 Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

Good day/night! I've been coding in Unity for a few weeks and now I'm playing around with the video player. I'm trying to recreate a TV in Unity so I decided to make class that allows me to create an array of video clips. I finished the class and fixed a few errors but Unity hit me with two CS0246 (The type or namespace of VideoPlayer & VideoClip cannot be found) error as soon as it complied. I searched the error online and looked for a solution, but none of them worked for me. I checked out the namespace docs, but I'm still confused. I don't have any scripts with the same name and I don't see any obvious bugs in the code. Here is what I have at the moment, it's only a few lines:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


[RequireComponent(typeof(VideoPlayer))] //needed or else I would receive an extra error
public class TVChannels : MonoBehaviour
{
    public VideoClip[] channels = new VideoClip[6];

    private VideoPlayer vidplay;

    void Start()
    {
        vidplay = gameObject.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
    }

    public PlayVideo(int id)
    {
        if (id < 0 || id >= channels.Length)
        {
           id = 0;
           return; //Since it's not void it needed a return statement
        }

        vidplay.clip = channels[id];

        vidplay.Play();
    }
}
```

I have been playing around with `[RequireComponent(typeof(VideoPlayer))]` since this is my first time using it (and believe that it may be responsible for the issue). I know it checks to see if the component is on the game object (and the Video Player is) and it's not attached to an object that doesn't have the player. If someone has an idea of what I can do to fix this, it would be helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that clearly describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. *Unity3d* is information you've provided in the tags, and *CS0246 issue* has no meaning. Your title should be clear and specific enough to have meaning to a future user of this site who is skimming through a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem, and your current title does nothing to provide that information.

Comment: @Tacoタコス Fair enough.

Comment: If you read the unity docs it tells you which namespace to add.

Answer (score 2):

The CS0246 error means the type you're using cannot be found in any namespace that is currently imported in your file.

According to Unity's [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.html), `VideoPlayer` is a class in the `UnityEngine.Video` namespace. This is specified by the `class in UnityEngine.Video` below the name of the type at the top of the page.

You now have two options.

The first one is to *fully qualify* the type name by writing the namespace before the type:

```
void Start()
{
    // we prefix VideoPlayer with its namespace, below:
    vidplay = gameObject.GetComponent<UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer>();
}
```

And then you do the same with `VideoClip`. This is the way used by the code sample in the documentation linked above, but personally, I find it a bit unwieldy. I prefer the second method, which is to import the whole namespace by adding a using directive at the top of your file:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video; // add this here
```

As a side note, even with those fixes the code you've shared wouldn't compile as is: `PlayVideo` is not a constructor, and therefore it needs a return type, which would be `void` in this case.